# ¿Cómo cambiar acción del nuevo botón "ir al sitio del vendedor"?

Tags: mercadopago, modal

En el nuevo flujo del *Wizard* de *MercadoPago*, al finalizar con el pago, aparece un botón de "ir al sitio del vendedor".

¿Existe manera de configurar la acción de ese botón? De manera que haga lo mismo que hacia el botón continuar en la versión anterior, es decir, que cierre el modal y continúe en la página del cliente?

Solicito ayuda porque se está presentando este error al presionar el botón.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El *backURL* que tengo configurado **cotizacion.do** y es quien recibía la respuesta con el "aprobado", y luego cargaba una página resumen de la compra.

Cambié el *backURL* e incluí el dominio para que encuentre el "DNS", y ahora me abre la página del cliente en el modal y no encuentro cómo cerrarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Según la versión actual de la API de MercadoPago (diciembre de 2017), se pueden definir 3 back urls, dependiendo el resultado de la transacción.

Estas back urls, son a las que se acceden, al hacer click en el link/botón "Ir al sitio del vendedor".

Para definir las backs urls, hay que hacerlo en el array de preferencias, que se envía a MercadoPago, desde el sitio web:

```
"back_urls" => array(
    "success" => "http://www.misitio.com/transaccion-exitosa",
    "failure" => "http://www.misitio.com/transaccion-fallada",
    "pending" => "http://www.misitio.com/transaccion-pendiente"
),
```

Se pueden definir diferentes páginas de retorno (transaccion-exitosa, transaccion-fallada, transaccion-pendiente), según el resultado de la transacción, o también, se puede utilizar una única página.

Como comentario adicional, a estas páginas de retorno, también llegan las siguientes variables, con el método GET (es decir, junto con la url de retorno): preference_id, collection_id, collection_status, external_reference, payment_type, merchant_order_id (las cuáles se pueden utilizar dentro del sitio web, para registrar el estado de la transacción).

Por último, también se puede definir, otra configuración llamada auto_return, en el array de preferencias que se envía a MercadoPago:

```
"auto_return" => "approved",
```

El cuál permite que, si la transacción fue exitosa, automáticamente se retorne al sitio web, a la back url definida (en este caso, para success).

Saludos

Comment: Gracias
Al presionar el botón de "volver al sitio del vendedor", sea cual sea el resultado de la operación, el back_url q definas se abre en el mismo modal, quedando la pagina del navegador como si no hubiese sucedido nada.

Lo único q funciono fue usando el auto_return, se cierra el modal y la pagina en el navegador hace lo q debe hacer segun el back_url de success.

Otro detalle la función JS onreturn="execute_my_onreturn" que se le coloca al código HTML del botón solo funciona cuando se cierra el modal usando la X, con el boton de "volver al sitio del vendedor" no entra a esa funcion.

Answer (score 0):

Si existe, como parte de uno de los parámetros de la preferencia existe: `back_urls` el cual tiene como finalidad definir las urls de redireccion de la pagina del vendedor para cada una de las situaciones posibles:

`success` | `pending` | `failure`

```
+-----------+----------------------+-------------+
| back_urls |                      |             |
+-----------+----------------------+-------------+
| success   | Approved Payment URL | String(600) |
| pending   | Pending Payment URL  | String(600) |
| failure   | Failure Payment URL  | String(600) |
+-----------+----------------------+-------------+
```

Referencia: https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/api-docs/basic-checkout/checkout-preferences/